# How to load API response Data into DropDown in React Native Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

This is my JSON Response Data. I have to load it in a Picker which is used for DropDown. This Data I am getting in a function.

```
{
    "api_res_key": "5678",
    "res_data": [
        {
            "course_code": "ICAJE",
            "course_name": "Induction Course for AJE"
        }
    ],
    "res_status": "200",
    "res_msg_code": "VALID",
    "res_message": "Course list selected"
}
```

This is my code for DropDown in react native expo app. Please suggest me How to handle this

```
<Picker
      selectedValue={this.state.DropdownData}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
          this.setState({DropdownData: itemValue})}>

      // Dynamically loads Picker.Values from this.state.userTypes.

      {this.DropdownData()}
    </Picker>
```

This is my function which loads the Data

```
DropdownData(){

            fetch('https://hashtaglabs.in/stctrain/api/master-access.php?api_key=1234&action=get_session_courses', {
                method: 'get',              
                header: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },          

            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then(async (responseJson) => {


                    if (responseJson.res_status == "200") {
                        console.log(responseJson.res_data);     
                        this.showLoader();
                        try {
                            await AsyncStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(responseJson.res_data));


                        } catch (error) {
                            Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
                            alert("Unsuccessful");
                        }



                    } else {
                        console.log(responseJson.res_message);
                        alert(responseJson.res_message);

                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
```

Comment: can you share your entire code in an expo snack so that we can check>

Comment: Due to some problem I am am unable to save code there. Can you please tell me how to load that JSON Data in Picker?? Or if there is any alternative method?

Comment: which picker are you using? library name

Comment: <Picker
   selectedValue={this.state.DropdownData}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
          this.setState({DropdownData: responseJson.res_data})}>

      // Dynamically loads Picker.Values from this.state.userTypes.

      {this.DropdownData()}
    </Picker>
This is what I am using.
This is simply react-native picker

Comment: i got that, i meant what exactly do you want to display in picker out of this {
    "api_res_key": "5678",
    "res_data": [
        {
            "course_code": "ICAJE",
            "course_name": "Induction Course for AJE"
        }
    ],
    "res_status": "200",
    "res_msg_code": "VALID",
    "res_message": "Course list selected"
} and also which picker library are you using ? check in package.json, i can help

Comment: Sir this is what I got from package.json ' "react-native-picker-dropdown": "^0.1.2",.'
And I want to display course_name from JSON Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm coding this off the top of my head so forgive any typos.

```
export default class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
             listItems: []
        }

        this.dropdownData = this.dropdownData.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
         this.dropdownData();
    } 

    dropdownData() {

       //....do stuff: success
       this.setState({
           listItems: responseJson.res_data,
       });
    }

    render() {
        var _items = this.state.listItems.map((n) => {
            return <Picker.Item key={n.course_code} value={n.course_code} label={n.course_name} />
        });

        return (
            //...
            <Picker
                 selectedValue={this.state.DropdownData}
                 onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
                 this.setState({DropdownData: itemValue})}>

             {_items}
             </Picker>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir this is not working. Any suggestion in order to improve my code??

Comment: It was very quickly put together. How exactly is it not working? errors? Could you update your code above with what you tried.

Comment: Sir actually I did not get the Data in DropDown list. There is not error showing

Comment: OK, so I'd debug - output values at each stage to see where it's falling down. is `listItems` populated? is `dropdownData` being called correctly? etc...